# Set image title according to dynamic number of iterations

Tags: r

My script below is supposed to create a word document with as many images as the iterations in the `for()` loop. In this case I use 2 but the issue is that this number may vary. Also the images' title should be set according to the number of iterations as well. Image1, Image 2 etc. Here instead of 2 images I create 4 and the number of iterations will not be 2 every time.

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

src <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
png(filename = src, width = 5, height = 6, units = 'in', res = 300)
barplot(1:10, col = 1:10)

dev.off()


current_dir <- getwd()

my_doc <- read_docx()


#Baseline Summary Stats Table
for(i in 1:2){
  my_doc <- my_doc %>% 
    body_add_img(src = src, width = 5, height = 6, style = "centered") %>% 
    body_add_par(paste0("Image",i,"asasa"), style = "Normal")


#Baseline Summary Stats Table

my_doc <- my_doc %>% 
  body_add_img(src = src, width = 5, height = 6, style = "centered") %>% 
  body_add_par(paste0("Image",i,"asasa"), style = "Normal")
}
#writing to word file
print(my_doc, target = "first_example.docx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain I understand your problem. The code works fine. It just prints four images because you repeat

```
my_doc <- my_doc %>% 
body_add_img(src = src, width = 5, height = 6, style = "centered") %>% 
body_add_par(paste0("Image",i,"asasa"), style = "Normal")
```

in your for-loop.

Try the following

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

src <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
png(filename = src, width = 5, height = 6, units = 'in', res = 300)
barplot(1:10, col = 1:10)

dev.off()


current_dir <- getwd()

my_doc <- read_docx()


# set number of iterations
n=3

#Baseline Summary Stats Table
for(i in 1:n){
  my_doc <- my_doc %>% 
    body_add_img(src = src, width = 5, height = 6, style = "centered") %>% 
    body_add_par(paste0("Image",i,"asasa"), style = "Normal")


}
#writing to word file
print(my_doc, target = "first_example.docx")
```

Comment: The 1st issue is that it should produce 2 instead of 4 but lets say this is ok but the second is that the number of itarations will not be 2 every time

Comment: Your answer is correct but still assumes that I set the number of iterations which should by dynamic like the logic I use for the images' names.

Comment: How do you intend to define the number of iterations? You will use the number of images found in a folder?

Comment: For the number of images yes. But for the titles I would say from the number of the folders beacuse images of every folder will have the same title.